# JQuery Sortable Item Change Value when Dropped

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two connectedSortable lists and when I move the items between each list, I want to change the prefix text of the item. Eg. If I move List 1: Item 1 to List 2, it would be rename List 2: Item 1 once it has been moved across to the new list.

Greatly appreciate any help on this one, cheers

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
  $(".dest").sortable( {
        update : function(ev, ui) {
            var label = something;
            $(this).append("<b>" + label + " </b>");
        }
    });
```